# MIPS assembly homework helpp

Tags: assembly, mips

This is the question:
write a program that takes twoinput values from the user and calculate the subtraction if the first number is greater than the second one other wise calculate the summation

this is what i tried:

```
.data
message1:.asciiz"enter number 1:"
message2:.asciiz"enter number 2:"
message3:.asciiz"the sum is: "
message4:.asciiz"the difference is:"

.text

main:
#enter the input by the user
li $v0,4
la $a0,message1
syscall

#read the user input
li,$v0,5
syscall

#store the enteres value in the register
move $t0,$v0

#enter the input by the user
li $v0,4
la $a0,message2
syscall

#read the user input
li,$v0,5
syscall

#store the enteres value in the register
move $t1,$v0

#compare the values stored in the register

bgt $t0,$t1,difference
add $t3,$t0,$t1
li $v0,0
la $a0,message3
move $a0,$t3
syscall

difference:
sub $t3,$t0,$t1
li $v0,0
la $a0,message4
move $a0,$t3
syscall
```

but when i try to run this it gives me the following error Error in line 48: Runtime exception at 0x0040006c: invalid or unimplemented syscall service: 0 that is when number 1 is bigger than number 2

and when number 2 is bigger i get this Error in line 41: Runtime exception at 0x00400054: invalid or unimplemented syscall service: 0

Comment: Well, yeah, there is no system call 0 (assuming that you're running this in SPIM/MARS), so I'm not sure why you're trying to use it. If you want to print a string, use system call 4 like you do earlier in the program.

Comment: I'm also not sure what `la $a0,message3` `move $a0,$t3` is supposed to do? What's the point of the `la` when you put a different value in `$a0` on the very next line?

Answer (score -1):

I've made the code somewhat workable, however be aware that it is not perfect but slightly modifying this could help.

```
.data          #data declaration
prompt: .asciiz "enter number 1:"
prompt2:    .asciiz "enter number 2:"
sum:    .asciiz "the sum is: "
diff:   .asciiz "the difference is: "

.text
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 4           #asking user for first prompt
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0

li $v0, 4           #asking user for second prompt
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t2, $v0

bgt $t1, $t2, subtraction           #here we're using the if-conditional statement
add $t4, $t1, $t2

subtraction:
sub $t3, $t1, $t2
li $v0, 4
la $a0, diff    
syscall

move $a0, $t3
li $v0, 1        
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, sum      
syscall

move $a0, $t4    
li $v0, 1        
syscall

end:

li $v0, 10
syscall

.end main
```

Comment: It is not really a suitable answer if you don't explain what you do and why.

Comment: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory, my bad.

Comment: Your code always prints both outputs, including whatever garbage was in `$t4` if you skip the `add $t4, $t1, $t2`.  You could add / la one integer and message before a `bgt` over a sub / la of the other message, then run a print string and print int system call with whichever message and integer your branch logic left.  Or if you always want to print both (unlike what the question asked for), remove the `bgt` and move the add / sub down lower to just add into `$a0` when you need the value there.

Comment: As it stands, this unfortunately isn't a good example of anything.  (That's one reason there's limited value in answering old Stack Overflow questions with multiple separate bugs: an answer explaining each problem will have too much stuff going on to be useful for future readers with a different set of bugs in their code.)